# Apple's SIPS tool on CentOS?

Tags: imagemagick, centos, sips

I just discovered Apple's `sips` tool ([Scriptable Image Processing System](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html)), and saw one person mention it is about 5x faster than ImageMagick for resizing images.

We have been using ImageMagick for years on our production CentOS servers and are happy with it, but performance is an issue. A large batch image resize can bring our beefy (48GB RAM, etc) server to it's knees, and we're often forced tho throttle/slow down the batch resize to keep other services running acceptably fast.

Is it possible to run sips on CentOS? Or is there some other similarly fast tool for resizing/recompressing jpeg images from within a PHP script?

Comment: How is your ImageMagick installed - I mean which options? There are known issues on multiprocessor servers when OpenMP option is installed.

Comment: ... following on from my previous, you can run `identify -list Configure | grep -i openmp` to see your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptable Image Processing System (sips) is a command line interface to Apple's [Core Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Image) framework which is [not open source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145358/is-apples-core-image-framework-open-source), therefore you can't run binary [Mach-Object executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) on Linux which has different architecture. So you have to look for some alternatives.